Java Annotation Processing doesn't generate new class
I'm trying to do an example annotation processing.
It doesn't generate any new class after compilation, I've seen many videos about it and cannot fix the problem.
I don't know where it is. I'm using JavaPoet and Google AutoService.
My code:
// ExampleProcessor.java
@AutoService(Processor.class)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.ExampleAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
public class ExampleProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ExampleAnnotation.class)) {
      ExampleAnnotation annotation = element.getAnnotation(ExampleAnnotation.class);
      String className = annotation.value();

      MethodSpec mainMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("sayHello")
          .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.PUBLIC, javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.STATIC)
          .returns(void.class)
          .addStatement("$T.out.println($S)", System.class, "Hello, " + className + "!")
          .build();

      TypeSpec generatedClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(className)
          .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.PUBLIC)
          .addMethod(mainMethod)
          .build();

      JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com.example.generated", generatedClass)
          .build();

      try {
        javaFile.writeTo(processingEnv.getFiler());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

// ExampleAnnotation.java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ExampleAnnotation {
  String value();
}

// MyClass.java
@ExampleAnnotation
public class MyClass { }

// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("java")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.auto.service:auto-service-annotations:1.1.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0")
}
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations["annotationProcessor"]
}

I've been watching many YouTube videos and searched internet but nothing useful found.
And yes, I have Annotation Processor enabled in my Intellij Idea.

As far as I know, you can't run an annotation processor at the same time you're compiling the annotation processor. Your processor needs to be a separate project. You can create a Gradle subproject for this, then in another subproject add it as a dependency using annotationProcessor(project(":<annoproc-project-name>")).

Oh my goodness, thank you so much! You saved me a lot of time, I appreciate it brother.
